# Block containers and the Visual Formatting Model

Tags: html, css, w3c

In W3C's explanation of the Visual Formatting Model, [Section 9.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) state that:

> a block-level box is also a block container box. A block container box
>   either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline
>   formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.

It gives this example:

```
<DIV>
  Some text
  <P>More text
</DIV>
```

and states:

> if a block container box (such as that generated for the DIV above)
>   has a block-level box inside it (such as the P above), then we force
>   it to have only block-level boxes inside it.

It achieves this, it explains, by wrapping "Some text" in an anonymous block-level box.

But if we add an inline element to the box:

```
<DIV>
    Some text
    <P>More text
    <span>An inline element</span>
</DIV>
```

The result—[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pps6b4pj/)—seems to contradict the original statement that a block container box "contains only block-level boxes or...only inline-level boxes":

It appears that the addition of the span creates a block-level box that contains *both* block-level boxes (one anonymous, one explicit) *and* an inline-level box.

Has adding the `<span>` established an inline formatting context? If this is true, doesn't that contradict the statement that an inline formatting context contains only inline-level boxes?

Am I missing something here, or is the W3C logic paradoxical?

**EDIT:**

So it looks like the spec itself fails to close the `<p>` element in the example. I've gone ahead and revised my code:

```
<DIV>
    Some text
    <P>More text</p>
    <span>An inline element</span>
</DIV>
```

And here is the new [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vj6xo7r/). It still seems to me like the span is acting like an inline-level box (i.e., it doesn't take up the entire width of the container.

Comment: The span is a child element of the paragraph, not the div.

Comment: @Quentin, see my edit

Comment: span is just like text, inline and can only hold phrasing ... such as p. but requires to be wrap in a block container such as text, if a block container is adjacent/on same level

Comment: Saying the spec "fails" to close the p element is a bit of a stretch considering the syntax is perfectly legal. It's not the spec's fault that you misinterpreted it.

Comment: @GCyrillus: You seem to be conflating HTML content models and CSS display models. Don't do that.

Comment: @BoltClock , i consider only html here , phrasing container or text should not stand aside block containers. (exeption for links that can be or one or the other ) ... unless spec change a lot since the las past year :) I believe reliable test should relay on valid test case ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is broken. The span element is a child element of a paragraph.

Let us use this for the example instead:

```html
<DIV>
    Some text
    <P>More text</p>
    <span>An inline element</span>
    <span>An inline element</span>  
</DIV>
```

Here the div generates a principal block-level box.

That box contains an anonymous block-level box containing the free text, a principle block-level box generated by the paragraph, and another anonymous block-level box containing the two span elements.

Each span element generates an inline-level box within that last anonymous block-level box (which establishes the inline formatting context).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the "Some text" and "More text" also participate in inline formatting contexts - ones established by their respective block containers (the anonymous block box and the P box respectively).

Comment: @Quentin this answers my question perfectly, thanks! Since I don't know where else to ask this, do all elements always establish either a block or inline formatting context? How would I establish an inline formatting context in the example above?

Comment: @symlink: If a block container box contains *only* inline-level boxes, then it establishes an inline formatting context. However, not all block containers that do not establish IFCs will establish BFCs - they only do in certain circumstances. You cannot trigger an IFC yourself unless you can ensure that an element generating a block container box contains nothing but inline descendants - but every inline-level box is guaranteed to participate in *some* IFC, even if that IFC resides in an anonymous block box.

Comment: @BoltClock so doesn't that make the concept of IFCs sort of arbitrary, or do they behave differently from non formatted containers?

Comment: @symlink: I missed stating that when a block box doesn't establish a BFC, its block-level descendants participate in whichever BFC is available. In a blank page with just your DIV and P example, all the block boxes participate in the BFC established by the root element (which is fixed). So, like inlines, every in-flow block-level box is guaranteed to participate in some BFC. Other than that, block formatting and inline formatting are two quite different beasts.